# digitalocean parse app dies on putty terminal close

Tags: parse-platform, ubuntu-14.04, putty, digital-ocean

I have a parse app on digital ocean and starting it with 
    `npm start` 
command from putty terminal on my pc at home but it dies when I closed putty terminal. How can i make app always run.

Comment: Follow the guide how tu run parse on digital ocean, it is the first thing that appears when you google it... I recommend using pm2

Answer (score -1):

Look at [Forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever), it's a good nodejs runner.